# How can I light a fire in this case?

Tags: gas-laws, heat

Is there any gas that contains oxygen so that it doesn't require oxygen from the environment in order to burn?

What I am trying to do is use LPG gas, which is fed through a pipe to a burner that is placed in an environment that has no air, somewhat like a vacuum. Is there any way to light the burner inside that vacuum environment?

A few *wild* ideas that I had included finding some gas that contains oxygen in itself. I may be wrong.

EDIT - The question doesn't end here. Please read the comments section below for any doubts that you might have. And if it isn't answered in comments section then ONLY comment.

Comment: you mean you want to burn fire in vacuum?

Comment: The burner would be kept in *partial* vacuum. Somewhat like a closed vessel. I was thinking that if there is something that contains oxygen in the gas itself? in other words, the oxygen/air would be mixed in the LPG/any other gas, itself.

Comment: Why dont you simply mix oxygen with the gas in the required amount?

Comment: Is that even possible? Considering the gas to be LPG (commonly used in Indian households).

Comment: You really don't need oxygen. Vacuum means there should be nothing there, so this is somewhat unanswerable. Not the downvoter though.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Vacuum in practical sense means, lower pressure than atmospheric presssure. What you're saying is in theoretical sense. I don't think meant by the word "vacuum" that nothing should be there. Then the question itself becomes meaningless!

Comment: Well, @Curious I'm pretty sure the reason for at least 2 of the downvotes is this thing's not being clear. How could we simply assert they meant the practical sense? We can't. That's the info the OP has to give, preferably in the original revision. Furthermore, it's also unclear what confusion the OP had in mind. Considering [this comment](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34384/how-can-i-lit-fire-in-this-case?noredirect=1#comment52391_34384), I can deduce they do not know what they're talking about.

Comment: What do you get inside a pressure vessel? It's not entirely vacuum but "somewhat like vacuum" and do notice that I've mentioned **somewhat**. I didn't mean to say complete vacuum. Anyway, now I guess the doubt is clear? If it still isn't then let me know and I'll try to clear the doubts. :) I'm just trying to know that is there any mixture/gas that doesn't require air from **environment** and can contain the air within itself. That's it. If there's something like this, then let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: Would you simply try to make a rocket or sth? All rockets take oxidizers with them. Also explosive often use added oxidizers.

Comment: If you burn stuff inside a vacuum it isn't really vacuum anymore, is it?

Comment: @Jori Please go through the above comments. Moreover, **I'm trying to burn fire inside an environment with no air  (I don't mean that the pipe from which is gas would come can't contain air). The condition is that the environment doesn't have air but you CAN provide air through the pipe from which the gas is coming. So, I'm basically asking that is it possible? Is it possible to mix gas with air/equivalent so that it burns in such environment?** ~ Made it bold because people are asking same thing over and over.

Comment: @Anoneemus After going through the giant comment chain, I'd like to ask: is the vacuum effectively finite in size? Basically, if you have a box (sitting on your desk) that's a vacuum and you want to know if you can burn something in there, the answer is "Of course. Fill the box with air first." If the box is effectively infinite in size (like outer space), there are some more interesting problems that pop up.

Comment: **Please add all relevant information to the question itself.** Going through that comment chain is a nightmare and I still do not really understand what you are trying to achieve. Comments are expendable and this question has now attracted so many, that they need to be cleaned soon. The post is unclear and the comment thread is too long, this is probably the reason for such a controversial voting (+4/ -5) and yes, I did downvote.

Comment: If you're really looking for heat in a vessel with no air, you should instead think about an electric burner. You don't need to worry about fuel mixing ratios, etc, because you do not require fuel or oxidizer. And you can keep it completely sealed if you want (even have a complete vacuum), with no affect on the heat delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient solution for your question can be the Hydrooxy gas (also sometimes called the Brown’s gas). Simply put its water split into hydrogen and oxygen. Hydrogen and oxygen can be combined back by ignition and can create a maximum temperature up to 2800 °C (around 600–700 °C hotter than burning hydrogen in air), which makes it a good fuel for metal welding and cutting.

Though 2:1 hydrogen and oxygen ratio is enough to produce water via combustion, but on a practical solution you will need around 3:1 to 5:1 ratio to avoid oxidizing flames. The temperature you can achieve by burning hydrogen oxygen mix varies, depending on the ratio of both gases used.

Hydrogen and oxygen can be obtained via simple electrolysis.

$$\ce{2H2O + Energy -> 2H2 + O2}$$

and combined back as

$$\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O + Energy}$$

It might be worth noting that for all practical purposes, the energy you use to split hydrogen and oxygen will always be greater than what you can get by combining them back (like what happens in every combustion engine, humans have ever created).

If you are planning to develop an actual application, there are many precautions that you would need to consider, the most important of which would be back-fire protection (a common problem with gas based welding), so that the flame doesn’t reach back into the gas tank, which of course will explode.

So goes without saying, but you might want to adopt some precautionary measures if you do use it in any practical application. Temperatures this high can seriously hurt a person even if the contact was for some milliseconds. It can also damage other materials if the flame is directed at them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [Oxyhydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen) is a mixture of oxygen and hydrogen, and has been or is being used in applications ranging from lighting to welding. The oxygen is mixed with hydrogen in a ratio such that the hydrogen is burned with the oxygen supplied in the gas mixture. This should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

TNT(trinitrotoluene),Potassium permanganate,Potassium dichromate,hydrogen peroxide,fluorine are some of the oxidising agent which you can use light up LPG without requirement of atmospheric oxygen.